# can you extract the NAMES of variables from $_POST?

Tags: arrays, variables, post, reverse

you can extract the $_POST array to the assigned values...

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){ $$key=$value;}
```

but how do you find the names of the variables themselves?

if i made a form saying

```
<input Name = "Turtle" value = "Slow">
```

then i do a :

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
```

i come out with

```
$Turtle = "Slow"
```

but how can i find out if what $Turtle *variable names* are contained in the $_Post array?

Comment: can you exxplain little bit, your question is unclear. do you want to find if turtle has value slow ??

Comment: no, no, no - i mean - how do i know if i have a $Turtle or a $Horse WITHOUT going though each variable if (isset($turtle)) and if (isset($horse))?  can i do some kind of "print each variable name in $_POST" rather than just see the values of those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_keys function will give you all the keys.

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
```

[PHP manual for array_keys](https://www.php.net/array_keys)